# Git error on checkout: "fatal: reference is not a tree"

Tags: git

It all started when I decided to figure out why the project I'm working on weighs so much. I've run the following script:

```
git rev-list --objects --all \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' \
| sed -n 's/^blob //p' \
| sort --numeric-sort --key=2 \
| cut -c 1-12,41- \
| $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

And figured out which commits have the heaviest files. Next, I would like to see who is the author of those commits and when trying to run something like:

```
git show --stat COMMIT_HASH
```

I get a pile of gobbledygook and when I try rolling back to the commit, I get the above mentioned error.

So my question is: **how do I find the author of the commit?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `git show` command should work. Either the hash is not valid or the commit object has been corrupted in some way.

**Updated:**
Your script returns object hashes, so probably the reference for that object is invalid somehow.

You wouldn't be able to get the author reference from there anyhow.

This might help, it will list all the commits where the object whose hash you provide has been modified:

`git log --find-object=OBJECT_HASH`

Comment: well I took the hash corresponding to the commit with the heaviest file, the hash was yielded by the bash script. But in that case , is there a simple way to remove the object?

Comment: but before doing that I would actually like to find out the author of the commit.

Comment: I have to update my answer. I ran your command and noticed that it returns object hashes, not commit hashes.

Comment: I've added a tip that might be useful.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I run `git fetch` before checkout specific revision and it work.